# Brute-Force polynomial algorithm in java

Tags: java, algorithm, brute-force

I need an enhancement on Brute-Force polynomial evaluation algorithm. I received the highest power of x (value of n), the value of coefficients of all elements of polynomial (a, b, c, ..)  as an integer array list. But I can't apply this algorithm on java: f(x) = ax^n + bx^(n-1) + cx^(n-3)+... + z How can I apply this polynomial on java? What is the algorithm for it? Any helps?

```
package brute.force;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BruteForce {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> coefficients = new ArrayList<>();
        int powerOfX, x;

        System.out.print("Enter integers please ");
        System.out.println("(EOF or non-integer to terminate): ");

        while(scan.hasNextInt()){
         coefficients.add(scan.nextInt());
        }

        Integer [] nums = coefficients.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            System.out.println(nums[i]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about algorithms or how to take inputs in java.

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: I am asking algorithm, I got all inputs above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate it with following iteration:

```
    double result = 0;
    Integer [] nums = coefficients.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        result = result *x + nums[i];
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

It is known as **Horner's method**.
The benefit of this approach for example of fourth degree of polynomial is:

f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + z

is transformed to:

f(x) = ((a)*x + b)*x + c)*x + z

Comment: That's really nice but you didn't use power of x value. How can I limit the algorithm by power of x? Actually you don't have to use power of x because it keeps going according to coefficients but I want to power of x value for just checking.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
double result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
   result += nums[i] * Math.pow(x, i);  // nums has coefficients in increasing order
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) to calculate a polynomial in a computationally efficient form.

user987339 has posted an implementation in Java.